# Where can I find out what version of Tinkerpop Gremlin, AWS Neptune is using

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I am trying to use `.valueMap().with(WithOptions.tokens)` in my query against AWS Neptune.   I get `MalformedQueryException`.  I suspect that this is a new feature in Gremlin 3.4.*

I have not been able to find a page that outlines what version of the syntax is supported by Neptune.

Where does this information exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the /status REST API you can find out precisely which TinkerPop version is currently supported. If you do something like

```
curl <my endpoint>:8182/status
```

You should see something like

```
{"status":"healthy","startTime":"Mon Dec 23 03:09:51 UTC 2019","dbEngineVersion":"1.0.2.1.R4","role":"writer","gremlin":{"version":"tinkerpop-3.4.1"},"sparql":{"version":"sparql-1.1"},"labMode":{"ObjectIndex":"disabled","Streams":"enabled","ReadWriteConflictDetection":"enabled"}}
```

**UPDATED 2022-05-18**

As an alternative to `/status` if you are using the Neptune workbench (Jupyter notebooks) the `%status` magic command will also produce the status information that includes the supported query language versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS [User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin.html).

> Amazon Neptune is compatible with Apache TinkerPop3 and Gremlin 3.3.2.

Comment: Using the /status API will show the version supported. Which since 2019 has moved up significantly.